# JQuery toggleClass method doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason the .toggleClass() function doesnt exist for this jQuery piece of code but the rest of the jQuery methods are working. What am I missing?

```
let listNode, imageNode, imageLinks;

let colapseExpend = (subject) => {

    subject.toggleClass("plus");
    subject.toggleClass("minus");

    subject.next().toggleClass("open");
    subject.next().toggleClass("closed");

    imageNode.attr("src", "");
    imageNode.css("display", "none");
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    listNode = $("#categories").find("h2");
    imageNode = $("#image");

    for (let i in listNode) {
        $(i).click(function (e) {
            colapseExpend(this);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `this` in `colapseExpend(this);` is a plain DOM `Element` object, no longer a `jQuery` object. In `collapseExpend`, you want to re-wrap in `$()`:

```
let colapseExpend = (subject) => {
    let $subject = $(subject)
    $subject.toggleClass("plus");
    $subject.toggleClass("minus");

    $subject.next().toggleClass("open");
    $subject.next().toggleClass("closed");

    imageNode.attr("src", "");
    imageNode.css("display", "none");
}
```